# Can I re apply?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, visa-bans

The decision:

> I have refused your application for a visit visa because I am
>   satisfied that paragraph V3.6 applies.
>
> Under paragraph V3.6 of the Immigration Rules a person must
>   automatically be refused entry clearance if false representations or
>   documents are used (whether or not material to the application and
>   whether or not to the applicant’s knowledge), or material facts are
>   not disclosed in relation to the application. A false representation
>   for these purposes is a lie, or a false statement in a visa
>   application, made either orally or in writing.
>
> In your current visa application form you have stated that you will
>   travel to the United Kingdom for 5 days to see your friend. You have
>   declared in your application you never been refused a visa for the UK
>   However, Home Office records show that you previously made an
>   application to enter the UK for which you were refused entry. You
>   applied and were refused with your application at DHAKA (BHC) 431876
>   on 14/01/2008 when you applied for a
>   visa to come to the UK. I am satisfied that you were given ample
>   opportunities to disclose relevant information about these
>   applications. The fact that you chose to omit such information
>   undermines your credibility and I am not prepared to exercise
>   discretion in your favour.
>
> I am satisfied that you have made false representations in support of
>   your application and that your application should therefore be refused
>   under paragraph V3.6 of Appendix V of the Immigration Rules. You
>   should note that because this application for entry clearance has been
>   refused under paragraph V3.6 of the Immigration Rules, any future
>   applications may also be refused for the same reason, under paragraph
>   320 (7B) of the Immigration Rules or paragraph V3.7 of Appendix V of
>   the Immigration Rules. A refusal under paragraph V3.7 of the
>   Immigration Rules may attract an automatic refusal period of up to 10
>   years. The period starts from the date of the previous event in which
>   the deception or submission of falsified documents or information was
>   employed.
>
> I am also satisfied that you have used deception in this application.
>   This means that future entry clearance applications may also be
>   refused under the Immigration Rules for a period of up to 10 years
>   depending on the type of application you make. The period of 10 years
>   starts from the date that the deception was used in this application
>   for a visa.

Comment: Why did you lie? You did not expect to be caught? Forget about ever visiting the UK in this lifetime, and maybe even the next.

Comment: You can apply and they will just send a refusal that brings the ban into effect. After 10 years, you _may_ apply after consulting a good solicitor having experience in handling such cases, which will cost you. Please see the linked question for a very good overview.

Comment: You've got a 10 year ban effectively.

Comment: I do not want to hide it. In 2008 I applied for student visa. It was my hand written passport and I do not have any kind of info from that pass which i can provide to them. And I just thought it was more then 10 years so do not need to maintains as well..

Comment: Too late for the OP, but for others in the future: In that situation, answer "Yes" to the question about past refusals, and give what information you do have or remember, no matter how incomplete.

Answer (score 4):

> Can I re apply?

Yes you are free to reapply. Your application will almost certainly be refused and you will receive clear notification of the ban. Don't let the use of the word **may** confuse you into thinking you have an out.